# Rails 3 rendering XML

Tags: xml, controller, ruby-on-rails-3

I have Rails 3 application (running Rails RC1), and I have the following controller:

```
class PluginsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json

  def index
    @plugins = Plugin.all
    respond_with(@plugins)
  end
end
```

If I try to render http://localhost:3000/plugins it works fine, showing me the HTML version. If I try to get http://localhost:3000/plugins.json, it also correctly sends me the JSON response.

However if I try http://localhost:3000/plugins.xml, I get the following error:

```
Template is missing

Missing template plugins/index with {:locale=>[:en, :en], :formats=>[:xml], 
:handlers=>[:rjs, :haml, :erb, :rhtml, :builder, :rxml]} in view paths 
"/Users/fcoury/Projects/backend/app/views", 
"/Users/fcoury/Projects/backend/vendor/plugins/haml/app/views", 
"/Users/fcoury/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.01@rails3/bundler/gems/
   devise-6754ae7/app/views"
```

Also, my ApplicationController is pretty simple:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  layout 'application'
end
```

I have tried taking out the layout line from the control, but same result.

Don't know if it's relevant, but I am using HAML and I only have one view file called `plugins/index.html.haml`.

Any ideas why this may be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment to the `respond_with` method:

> When a request comes with format :xml, the respond_with will first search for a template as person/index.xml, if the template is not available, it will see if the given resource responds to :to_xml.
>
> If neither are available, it will raise an error.

Try to explicitly call `@plugins.to_xml` and investigate the output of it.